# I am a new bee with JSON and I don't know how to perform serialization and deserialization in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

get links will be like this - http//192.156.120.192/Projects/cricket/index.php/api/api

```
public class Player
{

    public int playerId { get; set; }
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public string specialization { get; set; }
    public string battingHand { get; set; }
    public string bowlingHand { get; set; }
    public string bowlingType { get; set; }
    public object genericId { get; set; }
    public int homeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int eligibleTeams { get; set; }
    public object imageUrl { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject 
{ 

    public string methodName { get; set; }
    public int errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public List<Player> players { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Json.NET and it is super easy

```
// create a RootObject object
//..

string serializedRoot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myRootObject);

RootObject deserializedRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(serializedRoot);
```

Comment: could you brief it. Here i like to retrieve players list based on country

Comment: I think you might need to read more about serializing and deserializing. 
but in other words , when you receive a JSon Serialized object (normally string) , what you need to do is to deserialize it and this way you will retrieve the data inside it. 
For example in your case if you deserialized a root object inside it you will find the list of players if the object had that list when it got serialized

Comment: Thnx..Could you refer me any link that will helpfull to me...or If you have any blogs...

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationTracing.htm